# Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Please help me out below is my code. I want to be get rid of the error

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

interface userState {
  status: string;
  id: string;
}

export default function Details() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const user: userState = location.state;
  console.log(user.id);
}
```

[image]

Comment: as per this doc ,  https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-location
the state in location is unknown , you're trying to assign to a object that has consists of string  ,

Comment: Faizal thank you for replying. the issue is it will display the data on the console but on the browser it will display "Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type userState"

Comment: Thanks Faizal,  kavindu vindika help out

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid that warning by using [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) in typescript as follows only if it's really necessary.

```
const user: userState = location.state as userState;
```

Answer (score 1):

Overriding the type of `useLocation.state` might be more useful for future use.

```js
import { Location, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

interface userState {
  status: string;
  id: string;
}

interface UseLocation extends Location {
  state: userState;
}

// do not use *.d.ts for this declaration.
// just declare it in any *.ts file.
// this declaration is effective in other components as well.

declare module "react-router-dom" {
  export function useLocation(): UseLocation;
}

export function Details() {
  const location = useLocation();

  const user: userState = location.state;
  console.log(user.id);
}
```